# How to tell what the date will be in certain amount of time Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, datetime

Hi I have a project where I have to tell what the date will be in 4,000,000 seconds from now and I got it working except for the year. I'm doing this in a Command Line Tool application in Xcode.

**The code I'm using:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        long currentDate = time(NULL) + 4000000;
        struct tm now;
        localtime_r(&currentDate, &now);
        int actualMonth = now.tm_mon + 1;
        printf("The date is %d:%d:%d:\n", now.tm_wday, actualMonth, now.tm_year);
    }
```

**The result in the console:**

The date is 6:3:114:
Program ended with exit code: 0

Why does it log 114?

Comment: Where is the Objective-C? You've written a C program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSCalendar, NSDate, and NSDateComponents. Specifically, you can use the NSCalendar method [`-dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateByAddingComponents%3atoDate%3aoptions%3a) with `[NSDate date]` (to get the current date).

Using the Foundation framework's date and calendar classes frees you from having to worry about the complexity of calendrical calculations. You don't have to worry about leap days or leap seconds, or how many days are in a month, etc. There are a lot of subtleties that are hard to get right, and Foundation already has a well tested system -- there's no reason not to use it if you're working in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a timeInterval (equals seconds) to the current date and thus create a date in the future:

`NSDate *dateInFuture = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:4000000];`

This date you can display using NSDateFormatter in a datefield or print with NSLog
`NSLog(@"new date %@",dateInFuture);`

Comment: Thank you and I figured that Caleb and Volker but this is for a specific test in a book. So I have to do it this way, but your answers are right. Any suggestions on why or how to fix this?

Comment: If it is for a book you should try to solve it yourself... why it is 114 and not 2014... ? time(NULL) should give not long but time_t...

Comment: I've tried everything and searching the internet or asking on forums is one of the biggest ways programmers solve their problems. Would you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the *tm_year* member in *struct tm* only logs the number of years since 1900. So in 2014 it was 114 years since 1900 - this is actually working correctly. Just add 1900 to your *tm_year* member before printing the date.

Comment: Good Comment. Concise but accurate.  Fun Fact in seconds it'd be: 59918400000 :)